# PHP legacy code mysteries: Case-sensitivity in variable names

Tags: php, variables, legacy-code

I'm trying to make the client's legacy PHP application to work for PHP 5.3. I see this kind of code a lot:

```
$SETTINGS[cart][picsize] = "100";
$settings[user][time] = 123;
```

1) Are variables case-insensitive in PHP? Is `$SETTINGS` same as `$settings`?

2) I'm getting `'undefined constant'` for the `cart`, `picsize`, etc. and they don't seem to be defined anywhere in the codebase. Did some older versions of PHP allow referencing array indices without quotes, or what is going on here?

Comment: PHP will turn undefined constants into strings and treat them as such (as well as issue a warning). its best on your error logs not to do that, though. what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @watcher I believe they cause notices, not warnings.

Comment: @Sverri thanks you are correct, too late to edit my comment now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Variables are case sensitive, functions and classes are not.
2. It could have been that your PHP configuration had a certain level of error reporting turned off and you never saw the error. It might have worked for you because those undefined constants will get turned into strings. (credit: [@watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697370/watcher)). You should always reference associate array indexes with quotes, unless they are not a string. Strings should always be quoted, unless you have defined a constant. You do not have to quote integers, double or bool.

`$SETTINGS["cart"]["picsize"] = 100;`

`$settings[user][time] = 123;`

Those two statements are completely different and are in no way related as far as variables are concerned. Regardless if there only difference is upper case and lower case. They are still not the same.